# Set Global Variable or Repetitively Call Function?

Tags: android, function, global-variables, sharedpreferences

My app has some UI elements that are based on some settings from the user and I am not sure how I should go about coding this for best performance and there doesn't seem to be a good way to Google this to try to find if this has been asked previously.

Basically I want to check for the App Version UI set in the settings and I currently do it via a function:

```
public String appVersion() {
    appSettings = currentActivity.getSharedPreferences(APP_SETTINGS, 0);
    String prefAppVersion = appSettings.getString("appVersion", "v2");

    return prefAppVersion;
}
```

Then I will display certain UI elements via an if/else statement:

```
  if (appVersion().equals("v2")) {
     // do something here
  }
  else {
     // do something else
  }
```

Is this going to cause memory problems if I call the function 5-6 times within my app (getting a SharedPreference over & over again) or am I better somehow declaring a global variable that gets the SharedPreference once and then uses that for the tests? My only concern with that being if the Preference changes and the UI needs to be redrawn if the variable is not reset.

Your thoughts / input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the appVersion function will cause any memory problem, but maybe make appSettings as a local variable would be a better practice.

I don't understand the second question, do you mean how to know the preference being changed? [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) may help you.